# ActiveRecord: Disable certain methods like 'save' or make them private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, private

In Rails, I use a lot of models that have customized methods like `create_new!` which replace the built in methods (normally to wrap additional functionality without having to use filters, which I'm trying to avoid).

Because of this, I'd like to disable (or more elegantly, make private) some methods like `create` or `save`. Is there any possibility of making some methods private without any nasty side-effects?

Comment: How about keywords private and protected

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure that overriding these methods comes without unwanted side-effects.

Comment: Based on HTTP verb and URL pattern these methods are called automatically, GET /new for new, GET /id/edit for edit, DELETE for destroy, PUT for update etc. So, these methods shud b available and public. Custom private methods shud b called from these methods. To restrict certain users from certain actions use custom private functions like before_filter :authenticate_admin :except => [:show]. Without filters u can make conditional checks in action but that wont b nice. U may also use only one before filter function to perform all checks.

Comment: I'm *not* talking about controllers, but about AR models.

Comment: I guess using `private :save` and so on might do the trick. Investigating further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alias_method function to rename method you would like to obfuscate, and then redefine the method to throw an error or exception. Like for example,

```
alias_method :save_private, :save

def save(*)
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn("Method is deprecated and disabled, please use save_new")
  false
end
```

Comment: After his, how to actually save the object using `save_private` method?